# What is exact code used for SVM in sklearn library? What is its criterion to stop training?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

I am learning SVM. I have 2 questions in mind. First, what criteria use SVM to stop training? when I search for SVM tutorials, I found some. But, in all of them, training is done for example for 1000 iteration. But in sklearn, there is no limit for it. Still, SVM in sklearn perform much faster and sooner its over. How is it possible? What is its advantage over from scratch SVMs that perform much faster? Can some one give me a link to exact code that sklearn used for it, to compare and see why it is faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can learn from their documentation, [scikit-learn uses libsvm](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.svm) (of [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/liblinear/) in linear SVM) for sitting the models. Since scikit-learn is open-source, you can check the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/b102391d2f364996fe0a1beed763a0a95d5ed59c/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm). As you can see, this is a dense C++ code, so it would be unlikely helpful if you are just starting to learn about it.

> I search for SVM tutorials, I found some. But, in all of them, training is done for example for 1000 iteration.

The number of iterations is usually a poor stopping criterion as you never know how many iterations you need for a given problem. If you read section 4.1.2 of the [libsvm paper by Chih-Chung Chang and Chih-Jen Lin (2022)](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf), they describe there the stopping criterion that they used in detail.

> But in sklearn, there is no limit for it. Still, SVM in sklearn perform much faster and sooner its over. How is it possible?

Because they use a high-quality, highly optimized implementation of the algorithms that are written in C++. The toy implementations from tutorials nearly never can reach a similar performance to such libraries. The point of tutorials is to show code that is easy to understand, while the point of the library is that it is efficient, those two are not necessarily the same.

> Can some one give me a link to exact code that sklearn used for it, to compare and see why it is faster?

I already linked it above, but as I said, I doubt it would be useful at this stage. The production-level code would need to handle many edge cases, be fast, memory-efficient, etc so it would be much more complicated than the toy implementation. Reading it may be a good learning experience though. Keep in mind that those implementations would usually be in C++ or Fortran, so you would need to know those languages at least to some degree.

Comment: @AliM all the code is in GitHub, it was linked in my answer.

Comment: many thanks for your great answer

Comment: One more question. Are toy implementations like the library ones in case of improvement? For example, in algorithms like KNN, Adaboost, SVM etc, if we could improve the performance of toy implementation in accuracy or make it faster (but obviously not by playing with hyper parameters), does it mean that the library performance will also get better? For example by making the algorithm to use important samples rather than all of them and the toy algorithm performance gets better, does it work on the one that library uses as well?

Comment: @AliM I do not understand what you mean by that. By "toy" implementation I meant the most simple implementation possible that should not be used for any serious uses.

Comment: for example look at this link: https://github.com/adityajn105/SVM-From-Scratch/blob/master/Support%20Vector%20Machine%20From%20Scratch.ipynb. Does improving these algorithms for SVM, (of course not simply changing hyper parameters) lets say make the algorithm to use only some of samples instead of all and get same accuracy. Does that mean that the technique would work on SVM which sklearn library use as well? or not? In other words, does trying to improve algorithms like SVM,  KNN, AdaBoost via such mentioned Github link would work on the algorithm that sklearn uses?

Comment: @AliM a first approximation, valid at your current stage of learning, is that any "improvement" you come across that's actually worth using, is already incorporated in sklearn :)